# I need a vbscript if possible or a batch (.bat) file that changes tcp/ip printer color options to black & white

Tags: printing, batch-file, vbscript, colors, settings

> first of all, I am new to the world of scripting. I did a VBScript that adds TCP/IP printers (in a network) to a computer. So far I also managed to change the printers to perform duplex printing with a batch file. Now I need someway to change the printer color settings to print in black & white.

I'd appreciate if you could help me please,
Thanks in advance.

Code to add tcp/ip printer to computer:

```
 strComputer = "."
Dim objWMI:Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts://" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
Set colItems = objWMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem", , 48)

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _   
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")       
    objWMIService.Security_.Privileges.AddAsString "SeLoadDriverPrivilege", True


Install "167.221.10.249" ''printer IP to be added

sub Install(strIP) 
    InstallPrinterPort strIP
end Sub

strBasePrinter = "PRINTERNAME"
strPrinterName = "Xerox WorkCentre 7120 PCL6" '' Printer controller
strINFPath = "\\167.221.1.67\printer_7120\x2GCHAX.inf" ''path to .inf file

strIPPort = "IP_" & "167.221.10.249"
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCommand = "cmd /c rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b """ & strBasePrinter &    """ /f " & strINFPath & " /r """ & strIPPort & """ /m """ & strPrinterName & """ & /Z"
objShell.Run strCommand, 1, True

Sub InstallPrinterPort(strIP)

Set colInstalledPorts =  objWMIService.ExecQuery _        
    ("Select Name from Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort")

For each objPort in colInstalledPorts
    If objPort.Name="IP_" & strIP then exit sub     
Next

Set objNewPort = objWMIService.Get _
    ("Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort").SpawnInstance_
        objNewPort.Name = "IP_" & strIP
        objNewPort.Protocol = 1
        objNewPort.HostAddress = strIP
        objNewPort.PortNumber = "9100"
        objNewPort.SNMPEnabled = True
        objNewPort.Put_ 
end Sub
```

Comment: If you share the batch file for the duplex printing we can start from there...

Comment: Batch file to change a specific printer to print in duplex mode: 

setprinter PRINTERNAME 2 "pdevmode=dmDuplex=2,dmCollate=1,dmFields=|duplex collate"

Comment: I used "Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort" to add a tcp/ip printer

Comment: Is this helpfull: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/d9d89104-2624-436b-aa76-48bf060d5863/

Comment: Why are you using a script to do this? You can set the printer defaults on the server and when a user connects to it to print, they get those defaults.

Comment: Thank you rene, that is exacly what I wanted and it works

Comment: ops my bad, it didn't work after all, it said that it succeeded but there were no changes in the printer, but I think i'm getting close to the answer

Comment: and the printer itself in the server is set to print in duplex mode and black&white as default but when I add the printer to the computer it doesn't come with the default printer settings

Answer (score -2):

During my research i found this. I believe it sets the printer to it's default colors.

```
Option Explicit
Dim objPrinter
Set objPrinter = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
objPrinter.SetDefaultPrinter "\\ServerName\PrinterName"
' End of example VBScript
```

Comment: that code sets the printer as default and it doesn't change its settings